# unable to set cookie after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, cookies

I'm trying to set cookie with js-cookie.js after some ajax requests are done. 
If i put

```
Cookies.set('cookieName',object)
var cookie = Cookies.get('cookieName')
console.log(cookie);
```

inside success i get undefined, but if i put it outside of ajax callback i get printout (of course this is not what i want since this is finished before callback is done).

I tried also using $.whenAll() function (https://gist.github.com/fearphage/4341799) to wait for all ajax request to finish but again inside callback function cookie is not set.

Comment: Have you tried setting the cookie inside of `success: function(data) { ... }`? You can even pass a callback straight into that as a parameter of a function that you are wrapping with.

Comment: Yes, as i said i tried to put code above inside "success: function(data) { ... }"  but at console.log() i get undefined. I didn't understand second part of your answer.

Comment: Can you show the whole code for the success function you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('form.login').submit(function(e) { 
        $form = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get('someUrl')
        .done(function(data) { //data is returned async
            setCookie('weirdName', data, 1); //use async called data
        })
        .fail(function() {
            $('.error').show();
        });
    });

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Codeigniter? I just solved same problem, in my case set a cookie in ajax and outside ajax had different results, like different url's.

I can't comment yet...that's why I'm posting here.

Comment: But the question is tagged as laravel, so it's not codeigniter

Comment: Though i'm not sure it is relevant here at all, since i just want to set browser cookie after ajax (i don't care what backend is)